# Jquery change .prop href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the `#lienImg` `href` when the `.product_thumbnails` `li a` is clicked but it doesn't seem to work. Strangely, the .primary_image is updated...

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".product_thumbnails li a").click(function(e) {
      var imglink = $(this).attr("href");
      return e.preventDefault(); 
      $("#lienImg").prop("href", imglink);
      $(".primary_image").attr("src", imglink); 
      $(".product_thumbnails li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent().addClass("active"); !1
    })
    });
  </script>
```

```html
<div class="product_images">
  <a href="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353065/produit_08-294HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=1200" class="MagicZoom" rel="zoom-position: inner" id="lienImg" title="" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; outline: 0px; width: 576px;"><img src="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353089/produit_08-304HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;h=1000&amp;w=1000" alt="Image of Bol Or" class="primary_image" style="opacity: 1;"><div class="MagicZoomBigImageCont MagicBoxShadow" style="overflow: hidden; z-index: 100; top: -100000px; position: absolute; width: 576px; height: 384px; left: 0px; opacity: 0;"><div class="MagicZoomHeader" style="position: relative; z-index: 10; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 3px; display: none; visibility: hidden;"></div><div style="overflow: hidden;"><img src="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353065/produit_08-294HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=1200" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; width: auto; height: auto; position: relative; left: -350px; top: -413px;"></div><div style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma; position: absolute; width: 100%; display: none; left: 0px; top: 364px;">Please upgrade to full version of Magic Zoom™</div></div><div class="MagicZoomPup" style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; display: none; visibility: hidden; width: 276px; height: 184px; opacity: 0.5; left: 193px; top: 200px;"></div><div class="MagicZoomHint" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; visibility: visible; z-index: 1; left: 2px; right: auto; top: 2px; bottom: auto; opacity: 0.75; max-width: 572px;">Zoom</div></a>
  
    <ul class="product_thumbnails">
      
        <li class=""><a href="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353065/produit_08-294HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;h=1000&amp;w=1000"><img src="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353065/produit_08-294HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=300" alt="Image of Bol Or"></a></li>
      
        <li class="active"><a href="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353089/produit_08-304HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;h=1000&amp;w=1000"><img src="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353089/produit_08-304HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=300" alt="Image of Bol Or" data-pin-nopin="true"></a></li>
      
        <li><a href="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353110/produit_08-311HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;h=1000&amp;w=1000"><img src="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353110/produit_08-311HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=300" alt="Image of Bol Or" data-pin-nopin="true"></a></li>
      
    </ul>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using return in before executing code?Debug in console,You will find the issue . Update code like below,It is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".product_thumbnails li a").click(function(e) {
          var imglink = $(this).attr("href");
           e.preventDefault(); 
          $("#lienImg").prop("href", imglink);
          $(".primary_image").attr("src", imglink); 
          $(".product_thumbnails li").removeClass("active");
          $(this).parent().addClass("active"); !1
        })
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working in his context... See here: http://www.marieevedompierre.com/product/bol-golden

Answer (score 0):

As web developer said preventDefault() function not needed to be returned , also you need to point to the img inside your div .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".product_thumbnails li a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var imglink = $(this).attr("href");
  $("#lienImg > img").prop("src", imglink);
          // Notice you need to point to a image
    })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_images">
  <a href="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353065/produit_08-294HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=1200" class="MagicZoom" rel="zoom-position: inner" id="lienImg" title="" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; outline: 0px; width: 576px;"><img src="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353089/produit_08-304HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;h=1000&amp;w=1000" alt="Image of Bol Or" class="primary_image" style="opacity: 1;"><div class="MagicZoomBigImageCont MagicBoxShadow" style="overflow: hidden; z-index: 100; top: -100000px; position: absolute; width: 576px; height: 384px; left: 0px; opacity: 0;"><div class="MagicZoomHeader" style="position: relative; z-index: 10; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 3px; display: none; visibility: hidden;"></div><div style="overflow: hidden;"><img src="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353065/produit_08-294HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=1200" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; width: auto; height: auto; position: relative; left: -350px; top: -413px;"></div><div style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma; position: absolute; width: 100%; display: none; left: 0px; top: 364px;">Please upgrade to full version of Magic Zoom™</div></div><div class="MagicZoomPup" style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; display: none; visibility: hidden; width: 276px; height: 184px; opacity: 0.5; left: 193px; top: 200px;"></div><div class="MagicZoomHint" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; visibility: visible; z-index: 1; left: 2px; right: auto; top: 2px; bottom: auto; opacity: 0.75; max-width: 572px;">Zoom</div></a>
  
    <ul class="product_thumbnails">
      
        <li class=""><a href="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353065/produit_08-294HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;h=1000&amp;w=1000"><img src="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353065/produit_08-294HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=300" alt="Image of Bol Or"></a></li>
      
        <li class="active"><a href="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353089/produit_08-304HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;h=1000&amp;w=1000"><img src="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353089/produit_08-304HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=300" alt="Image of Bol Or" data-pin-nopin="true"></a></li>
      
        <li><a href="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353110/produit_08-311HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;h=1000&amp;w=1000"><img src="https://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/187353110/produit_08-311HR.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=300" alt="Image of Bol Or" data-pin-nopin="true"></a></li>
      
    </ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: #lienImg is a link not an image... you can see the code in his context here: http://www.marieevedompierre.com/product/bol-golden

Answer (score 0):

Remove the return e.preventDefault(); since it breaks your code right after initializing the var imglink.

```
$(".product_thumbnails li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var imglink = $(this).prop("href");
    $("#lienImg").prop("href", imglink); 
    // ... extra code
});
```

This line in your code :

```
 $("#lienImg").prop("href", imglink);
```

already changes the href attribute of lienImg to the clicked product_thumbnails link.

On the other hand the .primary_image is updated due to this line:

```
$(".primary_image").attr("src", imglink);
```

Removing it will not make the primary_image's image change to the clicked product_thumbnails image.